# aurelia - binding values to radio buttons

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to bind the radio buttons 'checked' status to the boolean values in my JSON object, but it's not being set.

template: (*jobReadinessItems* is an array of "Items")

```
<tbody>
  <tr repeat.for="item of jobReadinessItems">
    <td><input id="have" name="readiness" type="radio" checked.bind="item.Have" /></td>
    <td><input id="need" name="readiness" type="radio" checked.bind="item.Need" /></td>
</tr>
```

Item (json):

```
{     
  Have: false,
  Need: true
 }
```

cs

```
  public class JobReadinessItemDto
  {

     public bool Have { get; set; }
     public bool Need { get; set; }

   }
```

However, if I bind it this way it shows the values (but of course I can't set it):

```
 checked.bind="item.Have ? 'on' :  'off'"
```

Why does it display properly for "on/off" but not true/false?

http://plnkr.co/edit/G5Cw9i?p=preview

Comment: I don't get your model: does Have and Need are exclusive? So if Have is true then Need must be false and the other way around? In this case why do you model this with two bool properties instead of one enum property?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, they are exclusive and an enum would be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [cheat-sheet in the Aurelia docs](https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/cheat-sheet).

Search for "radio" and you'll find a few examples that might be a helpful reference.  One thing jumps out at me right away though:

`<tr repeat.for="item of jobReadinessItems">`

This should iterate over an array, but `jobReadinessItems` is an object:

```
{     
  Have: false,
  Need: true
 }
```

You should either change this to be an array:

```
[
  {value: 'Have', checked: false},
  {value: 'Need', checked: true}
]
```

...and bind it accordingly in your template, or change your template to bind to the object values directly.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

don't use **true** , use '**checked**'

myarr= {totalPrice: 0, productCode: 'abcd', checked: 'checked'};